# Matrix inverse step in SVD & ridge regression

Tags: least-squares, matrices, linear-algebra, svd

When we do OLS of $y$ on $X$, with $X$ being a n x p input matrix, the OLS $\beta$ is $(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$, and the Ridge regression beta is $(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY$. Also, the singular value decomposition of X is $UDV^T$ where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices and $D$ being a diagonal matrix. In equation 3.47 of **Elements of Statistical Learning** the author states
$$
\begin{aligned}
X\beta^{ridge} &= X(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^Ty\\
&= UD(D^2+\lambda I)^{-1}DU^Ty
\end{aligned}
$$

which seems to suggest that $X^TX = D^2$. But to arrive at that we first have
$$
\begin{aligned}
X^TX &=VDU^TUDV^T\\
&= VD^2V^T
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, I know $VV^T = I$ by property of orthogonal/orthonormal matrix. But there's a $D^2$ between them and I know matrix multiplications are not commutative. So how do we get to $VD^2V^T = D^2$?

Comment: I've migrated this to math.SE because the core of the question is about properties of matrix operations. There are lots of related threads on math.SE, possibly some duplicates: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=svd+ridge+regression

Comment: It’s not true that $X^T X = D^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that for invertible $n \times n$ matrices $A,B,C$, we can rewrite their product $(ABC)^{-1}=C^{-1} B^{-1} A^{-1}$.

$$\begin{align}
X\beta^\text{ridge} 
 &= UDV^T(VDU^T UDV^T + \lambda I)^{-1}VDU^T y \\
&= UDV^T[V(D^2 + \lambda I) V^T]^{-1}VDU^T y \\
&= UDV^T V^{-T} (D^2 + \lambda I)^{-1} V^{-1} V DU^T y \\
&= UD(D^2 + \lambda I)^{-1} DU^T y
\end{align}$$

Comment: In the 3rd to last line, why does $V\lambda IV^T = \lambda VV^T$? Does $\lambda I$ make it commutative?

Comment: $IV^T = V^T$ by the definition of identity. $V\lambda = \lambda V$ because $\lambda$ is scalar.